# Does Phinx help in query building

Tags: phinx

I'm trying to use PHINX as database query builder for SQL database. Does Phinx help only database migrations? 
The document also has only about configuration and steps for migration.

```
https://phinx.org/
http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you posted:

> Phinx is just about migrations without all the bloat of a database
>   ORM system or application framework

PHP has many options for ORMs, such as [Redbean](https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php), [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/index.html) and my favorite, Eloquent (comes with Laravel)